# MySQL 5.7 static build

Tags: mysql, compilation, static-linking

I'd like to build MySQL statically. I've checked https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/source-configuration-options.html, downloaded the source but unfortunately I'm only used to make and not cmake and I couldn't find anything relevent in the install instructions. So how do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling a static executable with CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648357/compiling-a-static-executable-with-cmake)

Comment: add `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES=OFF` to your cmake call.

Comment: I tried this option with mysql and got the warning `Manually-specified variables were not used by the project: BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES`.  Something may have changed with more recent versions of mysql

Answer (score 1):

In mysql-5.7 you need to use `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`.