# Compile Static executable with CMAKE

Tags: linux, c++11, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I am trying to build static executable but having no success in building up. It was working fine before adding following lines:

```
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
```

I want to convert it into static executable. Any help or suggestions?

Here is my cmake Code :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g -Werror -lpthread")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE
                               main.cc
                               audiofile.cc
                               button.cc
                               entity.cc
                               entity_group.cc
                               filter.cc
                               splash_screen_state.cc
                               sprite.cc
                               signal.cc
                               signal_chunk.cc
                               sound_edit_state.cc
                               splash_screen_state.cc
                               sprite.cc
                               state.cc
                               state_stack.cc
                               waveform_chunk_display.cc
                               waveform_chunk_select_button.cc
                               waveform_chunk_select_display.cc
                               waveform_component_display.cc
                               waveform_display.cc
                               wwest_app.cc
                               play_original_button.cc
                               low_pass_button.cc
                               high_pass_button.cc
                               mid_pass_button.cc
                               reset_button.cc
                               play_modified_button.cc
                               speed_up_button.cc
                               slow_down_button.cc)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_search_module(SDL2_IMAGE REQUIRED SDL2_image>=2.0.0)
pkg_search_module(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf)
pkg_search_module(NFD REQUIRED sdl2)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                    ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${NFD_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})

pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
                                      ${NFD_LIBRARIES} 
                                      ${GTK3_LIBRARIES} 
                                      nfd
                                      pthread)
```

I tried merging steps from the link, but not working and getting following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   src/CMakeFiles/wwest-outreach-app.out.dir/build.make:774: recipe for target 'bin/wwest-outreach-app.out' failed
>   make[2]: *** [bin/wwest-outreach-app.out] Error 1
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/wwest-outreach-app.out.dir/all' failed
>   make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/wwest-outreach-app.out.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Here is the link that I tried following:
[Compiling a static executable with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648357/compiling-a-static-executable-with-cmake)

Note: I added following line and it compiled but not statically as I still cant open the output file (.out) on other linux machines.

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you locate `libGLU.a` on your system? The linker cannot link a dynamic lib (`libGLU.so`) to a statically built program.

If you can find `libGLU.a` on your system, make sure it is available in `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If you /still/ have problems with cmake picking the dynamic library over the static archive, try adding this to your CMakeLists.txt above the find command:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
```

And last but not least, a reminder to clear your cmake cache so it isn't hanging onto `libGLU.so`.

Comment: Yes, I can locate libGLU.a on my system. I tried adding the line that you mentioned above and still getting same error. 

I didn't fully understand the cache part. How do I make sure that its being cleared out?

Comment: Find `CMakeCache.txt` and delete it. That will wipe out any cached cmake variables from the build, then rerun cmake to regenerate.

Comment: I did that. I added following lines and it compiled. But it is still not static as I cant run the output file on other linux which dont have libraries.

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

Updated the question.