# CMake build static executable file

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, dlib

I want to build an executable that includes all of libs that I used (opencv, dlib) so it can work on any computer.
Here is my current CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(adc_fr)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(/media/sf_dlib-19.9/dlib dlib_build)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        FDetect.cpp
        FDetect.h
        FExtract.cpp
        FExtract.h
        main.cpp
        )

add_executable(adc_fr ${SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(adc_fr PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-static")

target_link_libraries(adc_fr
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        dlib
        )
```

Here is the error I got when linking

```
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/adc_fr.dir/build.make:409: recipe for target 'adc_fr' failed
make[2]: *** [adc_fr] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/adc_fr.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/adc_fr.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I do have `libwebp.a` available in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

How can I force to use static `libwebp.a` instead of `libwebp.so`?

I did try to add `#SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")` but it still gave the same error.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling a static executable with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648357/compiling-a-static-executable-with-cmake)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
find_library(LIBWEBP_LOCATION libwebp.a)
target_link_libraries(adc_fr
        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
        dlib
        ${LIBWEBP_LOCATION}
        )
```

Comment: Got the same error. I think linker can find correct location, in this case `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but it still uses the shared `.so` lib.

Comment: Right under find_library, can you add this

        `message(STATUS ${LIBWEBP_LOCATION})`

And see the result?