# build static curl executable from source

Tags: curl, cmake, static-linking, dynamic-linking

- I'm trying to build a *statically linked* `curl` executable from source:
- When I grep around<sup>1</sup> the `CMakeLists.txt`, I find relevant flags:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git
$ cd curl
$ grep -rn "STATIC\|SHARED" CMakeLists.txt | head -n 3
87:option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" ON)
88:option(BUILD_STATIC_LIBS "Build static libraries" OFF)
89:option(BUILD_STATIC_CURL "Build curl executable with static libcurl" OFF)
```

When I add them, I see the static build:

```bash
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_STATIC_CURL=ON ..
$ make
# ... omitted ...
[ 77%] Linking C static library libcurl.a
[ 77%] Built target libcurl_static
# ... omitted ...
[100%] Linking C executable curl
[100%] Built target curl
```

But I can't make the actual `curl` executable to be statically linked:

```bash
$ file ./src/curl
./src/curl: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=a43b285880dba6b1c2a1301fafb6240e232dbcad, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

---

<sup>1</sup> is there any other way?

Comment: Usually, a CMake project doesn't have an option to make its executables to be statically linked. For achieve that purpose you may try to slightly modify the project's `CMakeLists.txt`, e.g. as in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24671474/3440745).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, the answer you mentioned worked for me, thanks. I think I'll post an answer (unless you want to?). IMHO, it would be better than marking this question as duplicate since it handles an *existing* cmake rather than trying to write a new one.

Comment: I would say the questions are duplicate: the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648357/compiling-a-static-executable-with-cmake) also provides some existing code, which OP wants to modify for achieve the desired effect. Note, that a duplicate mark is definitely **not a problem** of your question: I perfectly agree with you that "writing new project" and "adapting an existing project" are different activities. But those specific activities have the similar solutions, so it is better to have these solutions in one place, as answers.

Comment: BTW, would you find another solution for your task, e.g. by passing variables to CMake instead of modifying the project's `CMakeLists.txt`, then feel free to add the answer to the other question. The fact that the answer works for some other project, than the one provided by OP, doesn't make the answer bad or not suitable.